# Firebase storage suddenly stop working

Tags: firebase-storage

I was using firebase and everything worked fine.
Then suddenly the storage stoped working, and I got this error:

net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Only the storage gives this error - the database and auth work fine.
I don't think it's something in the code, because it happend suddnely, and even the simplest upload command doesn't work. I also didn't changed the storage rules.

What can be the reason that only the storage wouldn't have connection?

Comment: Did you find any solution for that?